# ASP.NET MVC3 - Action without reload site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have MVC3 app with form for edit data. This for include only dropdownlist.
It is any posibility to execute Controller method (HttpPost) without reload?

If not - how Can I return current site (because I have the same form in different sites).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, try XmlHttpRequest better known as AJAX to execute controllers. It's like sending a request from the browser to the server on a background thread which won't cause a page reload.

have a read of these blogs:

http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-MVC-2-0-and-AJAX-Part-1.aspx

If you can't use ajax, to get back to the same page you can redirect the user back to the referrer url:

```
public ActionResult Submit()
{
     // do something
     return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```